# Converting integer identifiers to pointers

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, hash, hashtable

I have ID values of the type `unsigned int`. I need to map an Id to a pointer in ***constant time***.

---

**Key Distribution:**

ID will have a value in the range of 0 to uint_max. Most of keys will be clustered into a single group, but there will be outliers.

---

**Implementation:**

- I thought about using the C++ ext hash_map stuff, but I've heard their performance isn't too great when keys have a huge potential range.
- I've also thought of using some form of chained lookup (equivalent to recursively subdividing the range into C chucks). If there are no keys in a range, that range will point to NULL.

  N = Key Range

  Level 0 (divided into C = 16, so 16 pieces) = [0, N/16), [N/16, 2*(N/16)), ...

  Level 1 (divided into C = 16, so 16 * 16 pieces) = ...

---

Does anyone else have ideas on how this mapping can be more efficiently implemented?

**Update:**

By constant, I just meant each key lookup is not significantly influenced by the # of values in the item. I did not mean it had to be a single op.

Comment: Also, please try to minimize the memory usage (similar to the chained lookup above...). Please don't suggest allocating an array with size  KEY_RANGE ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a hash map ([`unordered_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/unordered.html)). This gives ~O(1) look-up times. You "heard" it was bad, but did you try it, test it, and determine it to be a problem? If not, use a hash map.

After your code gets close to completion, profile it and determine if the look-up times are the main cause of slowness in your program. Chances are, it won't be.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a tree-based solution and your ids are in the range {0..n-1} then you can use a very cool data structure called [van Emde Boas tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree). This will yield all operations in O(log log n) and use O(n) space.

Comment: In my experience very painful to implement :) But yeah it's very impressive.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to get constant time.

I'd probably use a [B+Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree)

Comment: A hash map is constant time, most of the time.

Comment: It's still amortized O(1) on a statistically random distribution of keys.

Comment: I still feel that saying "it's amortized O(1)" is a great way to hide true performance. It could potentially be as bad as O(N^2) for N objects (even though very unlikely), but hey it's O(1) amortized!
This also assumes constant time object hashing method, which may not always be true.

Answer (score 1):

If your integer values are 32 bits wide, then you could use a 64-bit platform, allocate 32 gigabytes of memory (8 bytes per 4 billion pointers), and use a flat array. That will be as close as you're going to get to constant lookup time.

Comment: Side note: The fact that this is even *possible* today is pretty mind-boggling for those of us who grew up in an era where 64 kilobytes was a fully-decked-out machine.

Comment: By constant, I just meant each key lookup is not significantly influenced by the # of values in the item. I did not mean it had to be a single op.

Comment: Constant time means irrespective of number values you get the same time, what this comment describes is linear time.

Comment: Whole new meaning to "perfect hashing" :)

Comment: Can you explain why this is linear? I'm expecting each get() op to take a near constant number of instructions (for example the chained lookup proposal I posted in the question)

Comment: @Tom: "Linear time" is a situation where the lookup time depends directly on the number of items in the container. My suggestion doesn't do a search at all, but a single index: `a[id]` where `id` is the identifier to look up and `a` is the big array.

Comment: @Greg: can you spell “cache miss”? There goes your constant time, out of the window … ;-)

Comment: @Konrad: I was wondering whether anybody would pick up on that! The OP did say "Most keys will be clustered into a single group"... :)

Answer (score 1):

Reserve 4GB of your RAM for this, and simply cast your uint to the pointer. That's definitely constant time.

Answer (score 1):

As GMan suggests an unordered_map is probably a good solution.  If you are concerned about a large number of collisions in this hash map, then use a hash function that will remove the clustering of your data.  For example, you could swap the bytes around.

A good point to note is that you will probably spend more time debugging and proving a custom data structure than one that's already got good pedigree.

Answer (score 1):

How many items are to be in such a map and how often is it changed?

If all values fit into the processor's cache, then a `std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int,T*>>` with presorted values and binary search might be fastest despite the access being O(N).

Comment: Around 200k items will be in the lookup.

Comment: With a 32bit `int` and a 32bit pointer, that would be 1.6MB. I have no experience with this, but before I'd go and implement something like a vEB tree, I'd pick some integers that hash very well and try to find out how a sorted `std::vector` with a binary search compares to `std::unordered_map` performance-wise.